# How can I get Node.JS 0.12.0 running on AWS OpsWorks

Tags: amazon-web-services, opsworks

I would like to use AWS OpsWorks and as an application layer I would like to use Node.JS v0.12.0. However, I noticed that the latest supported Node version is 0.10.33.

I also noticed that OpsWorks uses a custom Node package - `opsworks-node`.

So my question is, can I:

- copy the OpsWorks cookbooks
- substitute the `opsworks-node` package with the one from this repo - `https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12`
- run the rest of the recipes unchanged

or will that break something (like something which is specific to the `opsworks-node` package and is not found in the regular `node`)?

If the above is not feasible, then how should I go about installing Node 0.12.0 using OpsWorks?

Comment: Reopened, as requested.  Go ahead and provide your answer.

Comment: CloudOps? Do you mean OpsWorks? AWS doesn't have a product called CloudOps.

Comment: @ceejayoz, yeah, stupid mistake. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty easy with only 1 hiccup.

I used the [`nodejs` cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nodejs) from the Chef Supermarket, which is compatible with the AWS Ubuntu 14.04 AMIs. I used this one in order to get a "regular" install - from a public package/source repository, and not from the repo that AWS maintains. However, the version of that cookbook's node was the same as on AWS - 0.10.x.

To get around that I created a simple wrapper cookbook around the mainline `nodejs` that overrides the following attributes:

```
default['nodejs']['version'] = '0.12.0'
default['nodejs']['repo'] = 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.12'
```

The default recipe then just includes the `nodejs` cookbook default one.

The only OpsWorks-specific change I needed to cater to (the hiccup) was the `node` binary location - OpsWorks looks for the node binary in `/usr/local/bin/node`, while the `nodejs` cookbook-installed package puts that binary in `/usr/bin/nodejs`. To fix this, I created a second recipe - `create-symlink`, which just creates a symlink of the installed binary in `/usr/local/bin/`.

The wrapper cookbook can be found here (with setup instructions) - https://github.com/zupper/nodejs-wrapper-opsworks